# Can I separate the debug, release web.config file from the website project?(.NET WSP, not web application project)

Tags: c#, .net, web, config

Before deploying the website, I would like to separate it into debug and release to prevent errors in posting it to the server with debug=true in the `web.config` file.
+++
Also, is there a way to do debug=true only when we test on localhost in `web.config`?

Please give a lot of advice to the C# novice developer.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? It is possible to have separate `debug` and `release` versions of `web.config` which get merged via transforms into your main `web.config` during build or publish. It sounds like you already know about that. That's based on your configuration profile. If your configuration profile is set incorrectly, though, that will still get published. But if you publish using the `release` profile, only the final transformed `web.config` should end up on the server, and thus won't be impacted by other configuration variables (such as `debug`).

Comment: Also, what version of ASP.NET are you running on? E.g., are you using ASP.NET Framework 4.x? ASP.NET Core 6.x? That _shouldn't_ matter as far as `web.config` transformations are concerned, but it'd be useful to get this question in front of the most appropriate audience for answering it.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in my question. First, I am using **NET Framework 4.0.** And I'm developing it as a **web service project**, not an application, using visual studio. When I build a project with web application, I can set it up by dividing debug.config, release.config in the web config file, but only **debug.config** is separated from the web service project. Is there a way to use multiple web config files in such a web service project?

Comment: Additionally, I'm developing from **localhost** to **debug = true**, and what's the way to avoid the mistake of deploying it to debug = true option when deploying it to a using server? I'd appreciate it if you could give me advice. Thank you. @JeremyCaney